# Create dataset by sampling from near-boundary of binary classifier to improve accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, classification, variance, false-positive-rate

Say I have some binary classifier $f: X \to [0, 1]$. I think the following bi-stage training method is straightforward to reduce error.

Step1. Sample uniformly from $X$ and create dataset with relatively smaller number of dataset. Then train the model $f'$.

Step2. Taking advantage of the trained $f'$, sampling from $X$ such that more datapoint will be sampled from the decision boundary of $f'$. Then using such dataset, train the model $f$.

I think, the above method is trivial and must have been investigated and improved much by researchers. Could you tell me the name for the relevant technique, if it has name?

Comment: I found that, it is actually doing the active sampling / uncertainty sampling with batch. So, I would call this technique as batch active sampling / batch uncertainty sampling.

Answer (score 0):

Such problem setting is called batch-mode active learning. Standard active learning setting which only samples single data point per iteration cannot be usually applied to deep-learning. This is mainly because 1) single data point hardly change the network weight 2) training the entire network per each active learning iteration take really long cost. Thus, batch-mode active learning have been studied primarily for image classification.

The related paper can be found in

> Hoi, Steven CH, et al. "Batch mode active learning and its application
> to medical image classification." Proceedings of the 23rd
> international conference on Machine learning. 2006.
>
> Wei, Kai, Rishabh Iyer, and Jeff Bilmes. "Submodularity in data subset
> selection and active learning." International conference on machine
> learning. PMLR, 2015.
>
> Sener, Ozan, and Silvio Savarese. "Active learning for convolutional
> neural networks: A core-set approach." arXiv preprint arXiv:1708.00489
> (2017).